# Average velocity of rocket

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity, displacement

> A rocket is accelerating straight up from the earth's surface. At $1.15$ s after liftoff, the rocket clears the top of its launch platform, $63$ m above the ground. After an additional $4.75$ s, it is $1.00$ km above the ground. Calculate the magnitude of the average velocity of the rocket for the $4.75$ s part of its flight and the first $5.90$ s of its flight.

I don't think the acceleration is constant, so the velocity should be given by $v(t) = v(0) + \int_0^t a(u) du$ and the displacement should be given by $x(t) = x(0) + \int_0^t x(u) du.$ If I assume the acceleration function $a(t)$ has the form $at + b$, I get that $v(t) = \frac{a}2 t^2 + bt$ and $x(t) = \frac{a}6 t^3 + b\frac{t^2}2.$ Then plugging the values $x(5.9) = 1000$ and $x(1.15) = 63$ should yield the desired result. However, I'm not sure if this is correct, especially since the value of $b$ I get from the resulting system of equations is $104.409,$ when the acceleration should probably be $-9.8$ when $t=0.$

However, once I find the velocity function, I should be able to find the average acceleration easily using the formula $v_{av} = \frac{v_2 - v_1}{t_2 - t_1},$ where $v_{av}$ is the average velocity, $v_2$ is the velocity at time $t_2$ and $v_1$ is the velocity at time $t_1.$

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.